# Is there a way to make a DashTable in Dash non-interactive?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

Just have a function that returns a small DF, which is output to front-end through a dash table. How can I make the cells and rows and columns non clickable, and non hoverable, so that users just see the words and values of the DF, and can’t interact with it?

Or is there a different wrapper object I should use to output the DF to the app, but still be able to maintain the CSS styling elements of CSS like font size, width, etc?

Here is the default DashTable code to quickly set up a test env:
As you can see, the cells can be clicked on and highlighted in red, but I would like it just to be static.

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer through some digging.
Insert this into your custom css file that runs on startup

```
.dash-spreadsheet-container .dash-spreadsheet-inner table {
        --accent: transparent  !important;
        --border: transparent !important;
        --text-color: transparent !important;
        --hover: transparent !important;
        --background-color-ellipses: transparent !important;
        --faded-text: transparent !important;
        --faded-text-header: transparent !important;
        --selected-background: transparent !important;
        --faded-dropdown: transparent !important;
        --muted: transparent !important;
}
```